# Android Jackson Library parsing

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting a "JSONObject can't be cast to ClassResponse" error after getting a server response.  Im guessing its because the response from server doesn't match the fields in ClassResponse?  Is it because of the "data" struct in the JSON response? I have a setter for each of the fields but not sure what I am doing wrong. Is there a way to change the annotation for the Jackson library to parse other layers of the json object?  for instance..

@JsonProperty("data:accessToken")  or something of that nature... or is that even necessary?

server response:

```
{
    success: "true"
    message: "Record Created"
    data: {
      userToken : "1"
          }
}
```

ClassResponse:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class LoginResponse extends Response<LoginResponse.Result>
{
    public static class Result
    {

        private String mUserToken;
        private String mAccessToken;
        private String mUserId;

        public String getUserToken(){
            return mUserToken;
        }

        @JsonProperty("userToken")
        public void setUserToken(final String aUserToken){
            mUserToken = aUserToken;
        }

        public String getAccessToken(){
            return mAccessToken;
        }

        @JsonProperty("accessToken")
        public void setAccessToken(final String aAccessToken){
            mAccessToken = aAccessToken;
        }

        public String getUserId(){
            return mUserId;
        }

        @JsonProperty("user_id")
        public void setUserId(final String aUserId){
            mUserId = aUserId;
        }
    }
}

    (edit)
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void accessDataLayer(final String data) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(data);

        mUserToken = jobj.getString("userToken");
        mAccessToken = jobj.getString("accessToken");
        mUserId = jobj.getString("user_id");

    }



@Override
public RESULT loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception{
    final String url = buildUrl();

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    String response;

    try{
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        JSONObject submitInfo = new JSONObject();
        submitInfo = buildParams(entity);

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.write(submitInfo.toString());
        out.close();

            response = readStream(conn.getErrorStream());

        conn.disconnect();
    }
    return parse(response);
```

Comment: Show the full class and the code you use to deserialize the json.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are trying a desserialize a whole JSONObject in your "LoginResponse.class" collection. That's no ok, because LoginResponse is an element of the Array "data" in your JSON response, but NOT whole response! To get the array you should write something like this

```
 JsonArray data = (JsonArray) JSONObject.getAsJsonArray("data")
```

And after that you'll get your "data" collection

Comment: hey whizz, thank you for your response, I thought of that yesterday after I posted and changed to something like this.. however I am still getting the unable to cast error ( put the change at bottom of original post )

Comment: @AK824 i've just looked at your code changes, can you post a method where you are connecting to server and call "accessDataLayer"? I think problem may be that you give a json as String in your "accessDataLayer"

Comment: @AK824 I advise you to use https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ instead Jackson. It is a library thats let you to get an objects from json without any annotations, parsing or something boring things. Just rename a fields in your class Result to same names in your json "data" struct, and now you can work with gson, enjoy.

Comment: @whizzkey I am using robospice and jackson, i am trying to move off an old api onto a new one without changing libraries...  I have parent/child result classes to handle the different values of the incoming json for "success" and "data" but having the hardest time finding the right combination for this project

Comment: @AK824 i told you use a gson, its a realy simplest way to get any objects from json into java object. Read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20467664/2504010